# mod_wsgi fails when it is asked to read a file

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm having a puzzling issue where when my Flask application requires reading a file from disk, it fails with the following error:

```
[Mon Aug 26 22:29:48 2013] [error] [client 67.170.62.218] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=15678): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'flaskapp' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.14164.5.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
```

When using the Flask development server, or running an application that does not read files, it works fine.

**directory structure:**

```
/flaskapp
    /static
        style.css
    /templates
        index.html
    flaskapp.py
    flaskapp.wsgi
    config.json
```

**flaskapp.py:**

```
import flask
import json

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
#config = json.loads(open('config.json', 'r').read())

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"
    #return flask.render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/flaskapp')
from flaskapp import app as application
```

**sites-available:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /root/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
    WSGIScriptReloading On

    <Directory /root/flaskapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the socket error see:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets

BTW, don't use relative path names for files you want to load either:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory

Although commented out right now, loading config.json in your code as you are would also usually fail.